# Subfield of $k(t)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ be a field (though I am mainly interested in the case when $k = \mathbb{C}$) and let $k(t)$ be the rational function field over $k$ in the variable $t$, i.e.
$$
k(t) : = \left\{ \frac{f(t)}{g(t)} : f(t) , g(t) \in k[t] \right\}.
$$
I am wondering whether $A = k(t)$, where
$$
A : = \left\{\sum_{i = -m}^n a_{i}x^i : m,n \in \mathbb{N} , a_{i} \in k  \right\}.
$$
Clearly $A \subseteq k(t)$. In order to show $k(t) \subseteq A$, it suffices to show that $f(t)/g(t) \in A$ for $f(t) , g(t) \in k[t]$ with $\deg f(t) < \deg g(t)$ by the Division Algorithm. From here, it seems like we would need to invoke some partial fraction decomposition argument, which becomes messy, especially if $k$ is not algebraically closed.

Any hint or suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Pick $k=\mathbb{C}$. Then $g(x)=(x+1)^{-1}$ is not in $A$. Functions in $A$ have only poles at the origin, but $g$ has one at $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is false in any field. Consider the rational function $1/(1-z).$ If this could be formally represented as a Laurent series with $m$ finite, as you desire, then $z^m/(1-z)$ would be formally equal to some polynomial. So, $z^m/(1-z) = a_0 + a_1z + \cdots + a_nz^n.$ Multiply by $1-z$ to get $z^m = a_0 + (a_1-a_0)z + \cdots + (a_n-a_{n-1})z^n - a_nz^{n+1}.$ So, all of these coefficients are zero except for one. Which one could it be?

If $a_k - a_{k-1}$ is the nonzero coefficient, for some $k \leq n,$ then we see that $a_{k+1} - a_k = 0,$ so that $a_{k+1} = a_k.$ Similarly, $a_k, a_{k+1}, ..., a_n$ are all equal. In particular, the $-a_nz^{n+1}$ term will not be zero!

If $a_n \neq 0$, so that the $-a_nz^{n+1}$ term is our unique nonzero term, a similar contradiction arises, since if $a_0 = a_1-a_0 = \cdots = a_n - a_{n-1} = 0,$ then you can deduce $a_n = 0,$ contradicting that $a_n \neq 0.$